# Column Series With different color on a different interval at x-axis fill in same series?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, livecharts

I'm trying to implement a speed/time plot UI, i'm using WPF with the MVVM Pattern and Live-Charts by beto-rodriguez as my plot library.
I am using Column Series.

i have two issues:
1) i have to start the series in middle of the x-axis how to do this? e.g if i set the min value as 7 the graph starts the x axis as 7 taking it the first point but i want x - axis to start at 1 but graph plotting should start at 7.

2) i have to change the color of the series at a certain condition say when x= 10 i want it to be shown as blue but when x= 17 i want to show the same series as pink only for that value rest at all points it should be of the original color.

Any Pointers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a couple of options:

Use a different series for every point:

```
<lvc:CartesianChart>
   <lvc:CartesianChart.Series>
      <lvc:ColumnSeries Fill="Red" />
      <lvc:ColumnSeries Fill="Blue" />
```

You can use set them using a mapper, for example: https://lvcharts.net/App/examples/v1/wpf/Point%20State

Comment: please let me know if i am wrong, it will create two different series, what i want is i am having two series for network upload and download shown as a live chart ... now what i want is when my vpn is disconnected the color of both the series changes at the point when the vpn got disconnected, but before that point series should be of original color... and these series should keep on moving in live chart...the series i have to use is Column series.

Comment: thanks a ton @bto.rdz it worked for me through this link :)

Answer (score 2):

Hi I fixed this problem with this code:
In my case I need the column with the actual hour data in different color respect the other.

Code Behind:

```
 public Brush DangerBrushFill { get; set; } = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.DarkOrange);
 public Brush DangerBrushStroke { get; set; } = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black);
 public CartesianMapper<Double> Mapper { get; set; }
 public ChartValues<double> ChartValues { get; private set; }

        Mapper = Mappers.Xy<Double>()
            .X((item, index) => item)
            .Y((item, index) => index)                
            .Fill((item, index) => 
            (item > 0 && index == DateTime.Now.Hour - 1) ? DangerBrushFill : null)
            .Stroke((item, index) =>
            (item > 0 && index == DateTime.Now.Hour - 1) ? DangerBrushFill : null);

        SeriesCollection = new SeriesCollection
        {
            new RowSeries
            {
                Configuration=Mapper,
                Values = ChartValues,
                StrokeThickness = 3
            }
        };
```

Xaml:

```
 <lvc:CartesianChart    Hoverable="False"                            
                        Series="{Binding SeriesCollection}">
```

I Hope this help you.

Answer (score 0):

1) Would it be possible that you fill the values of you ColumnSeries with 0's at the beginning? For example the values of the ColumnSeries will be like this, if you want to start your diagram from 7: `{0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 10, 12, 14, 16}`

2) Could you give another example of a condition? Do you really mean x=10 or probably y=10? Is this [Issue](https://github.com/beto-rodriguez/Live-Charts/issues/602) related to your question?

Comment: thanks for the response , yeah i tried earlier with that it works fine, was looking for any other better solution .
2) i have a condition when internet gets disconnected i want to show blue color on x-axis and when user again connects it has to show pink color so thats why specified at a certain x - axis value if i can change the color of series in Live charts.

Comment: i raised the issue on github live charts but didnt recieve any response :)

Comment: @Yvonnila Did you find how to fill values of ColumnSeries one by one?

Comment: @fatihyildizhan No I didn't. Sorry it's a long time that I didn't work with LiveCharts...