# LiveCharts GColumnSeries with different fill colors based on conditions

Tags: c#, livecharts

Someone has posted a similar question here 
[Column Series With different color on a different interval at x-axis fill in same series?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45457336/column-series-with-different-color-on-a-different-interval-at-x-axis-fill-in-sam)

He's managed to get the result he want, but I am still struggling with it. How do I fill different colors of GColumnSeries bars based on conditions?

```
Mapper = Mappers.Xy<ObservableValue>()
.X((item, index) => index)
.Y(item => item.Value)
.Fill(item => item.Value > 200 ? DangerBrush : null)
.Stroke(item => item.Value > 200 ? DangerBrush : null);
```

This code works only in GLineSeries, but GColumnSeries seems to ignore that. Because no matter what the value is, the color is blue (maybe blue is the default color?)

Answer (score 0):

This is weird, when I change the type from GColumnSeries to ColumnSeries, it condition works. When I move my mouse cursor to the chart area, I get this message:

Object reference not set to an instance of an object

[image: error message]

Edit:

To fix the error I had to cheat, because I couldn't find a better way deal with this.

```
    private void Dispatcher_UnhandledException(object sender, DispatcherUnhandledExceptionEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Exception.StackTrace.StartsWith("   at LiveCharts.Geared.GearedValues`1.a.b(ChartPoint A_0)"))
        {
            e.Handled = true;
            return;
        }
        MessageBox.Show(string.Format("{0} - {1}", e.Exception.Message, e.Exception.StackTrace));
    }

    private void Current_DispatcherUnhandledException(object sender, DispatcherUnhandledExceptionEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Exception.StackTrace.StartsWith("   at LiveCharts.Geared.GearedValues`1.a.b(ChartPoint A_0)"))
        {
            e.Handled = true;
            return;
        }
        MessageBox.Show(string.Format("{0} - {1}", e.Exception.Message, e.Exception.StackTrace));
    }
```

Maybe [Beto Rodriguez](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2979430/bto-rdz) from LiveCharts can look into this and check if it's a bug.