# Different colors for each value in a ColumnSeries

Tags: c#, wpf, livecharts

I am using LiveCharts in WPF to create a Cartesian Chart with columns. The values come from a list which in turns is populated with values from a database.

Everything works fine except I would like each column to have a different fill. It does not matter what color, just a random color for each seperate column. Also, I do not want to create a new series for each value because there are too many values.

The Mappers method from the similar question does not work for me since the example changes color according to how high the value is. I want different colors for each different axis label.

This is the part of my code where I create the series:

```
cartesianChart.Series.Add(new ColumnSeries
{
    Title = "Column Chart: ",
    Fill = Brushes.CadetBlue,
    Values = valuesList.AsChartValues(),
    DataLabels = true,
    LabelPoint = point => (point.Y).ToString(),
});
```

This is what the chart looks like:

[image: Chart]

Any ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Column Series With different color on a different interval at x-axis fill in same series?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45457336/column-series-with-different-color-on-a-different-interval-at-x-axis-fill-in-sam)

Comment: Slightly differs but may be useful in adapting to your situation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use a SeriesCollection in LiveCharts it will automatically assign a different color to every individual series in the collection.

For this example I have taken a snippet from one of my projects which adds multiple series and has a separate List which contains all the series names. This will loop and add each series in to the collection and add the series data and series name from the list.

**Live Charts Geared Example:**

```
SeriesCollection = new LiveCharts.SeriesCollection();

List<GearedValues<long>> seriesList = new List<GearedValues<long>>();

seriesList.Add(Data1.AsGearedValues().WithQuality(Quality.Low));
seriesList.Add(Data2.AsGearedValues().WithQuality(Quality.Low));

for(int i = 0; i < seriesName.Count(); ++i)
{
    SeriesCollection.Add(new GColumnSeries
    {
        Values = seriesList[i],
        Name = seriesName[i],
        Fill = System.Windows.Media.Brushes.Transparent,
        StrokeThickness = 1,
        PointGeometry = null,
        LineSmoothness = 0,
    });
}
```

**Standard Live Charts Example**

```
SeriesCollection = new LiveCharts.SeriesCollection();

List<ChartValues<long>> seriesList = new List<ChartValues<long>>();

seriesList.Add(Data1);
seriesList.Add(Data2);

for(int i = 0; i < seriesName.Count(); ++i)
{
    SeriesCollection.Add(new ColumnSeries
    {
        Values = seriesList[i],
        Name = seriesName[i],
        Fill = System.Windows.Media.Brushes.Transparent,
        StrokeThickness = 1,
        PointGeometry = null,
        LineSmoothness = 0,
    });
}
```

The SeriesCollection colors are preset for each series in the collection, however these default colors can be modified.

Answer (score 0):

try DataPoint class:

```
DataPoint p=new DataPoint(chart1.Series["Celler"]);
p.SetValueY(cellVoltage[cell]);
p.Label=cellname[cell];//string
p.Color=Color.FromArgb(255 - cell * 20, 255, 80cell*20);
chart1.Series["Celler"].Points.Add(p);
```



Answer (score 0):

I achieved this using the Series.OnPointMeasured event. See: [ConditionalDraw Example](https://github.com/beto-rodriguez/LiveCharts2/blob/master/samples/BlazorSample/Pages/General/ConditionalDraw.razor)

```
var index = 0;
var colSeries = new ColumnSeries
{
    Title = "Column Chart: ",
    Fill = Brushes.CadetBlue,
    Values = valuesList.AsChartValues(),
    DataLabels = true,
    LabelPoint = point => (point.Y).ToString(),
}
colSeries.OnPointMeasured(point =>
{
    if (point.Visual is null) return;
    point.Visual.Fill = new SolidColorPaint(SKColor.FromHsl(index * 20, 50, 50));
    index++;
});
cartesianChart.Series.Add(colSeries);
```

Basically this event allows you to set the fill of the Geometry I think. You can use the point value to determine the fill color as in their example, or as above I just used an index to calculate the color Hue. You can adapt this for a indexed color etc.