# How to change color of selected ChartPoints in LiveCharts2?

Tags: wpf, livecharts

I'm migrating a small WPF app from LiveCharts to LiveCharts2. I would like to change the color of few `ChartPoints` in the `CartesianChartControl` based on their values. In the (*old*) LiveCharts implementation, I created a custom mapper, which returns a new `SolidColorBrush` for these points (see [LiveCharts: Color series with different color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45457336/column-series-with-different-color-on-a-different-interval-at-x-axis-fill-in-sam)).

In LiveCharts2 the mapper implementation has been changed. I found a way how to implement own mapper for the values ([LiveCharts2 - Overview Mappers](https://livecharts.dev/docs/WPF/2.0.0-beta.920/Overview.Mappers)), but I'm still looking for a way to change the `ChartPoint` color. Which property should be used to change the `Fill` settings of the `ISeries` instance?

Any ideas?

Comment: This changed drastically in v2, I have noticed this confusion on many users, I will consider an example about this feature.

Comment: Do you have some time estimation or how I can proceed?

Comment: There is now an axample: https://livecharts.dev/docs/WPF/2.0.0-beta.950/samples.general.mapPoints

Comment: Thanks for your support and the fast response. Because I use VB the converted version of your code is posted below. The only one limitation to me is the necessity to use `Object` in the lambda method. The real object type is `CharPoint(Of TModel, TVisual, TLabel)`. 
Is it possible to define an interface for all `TVisual` and `TLabel` types? This will simplify the access and increase the type checking.

Answer (score 1):

The LiveCharts2 has a great architecture, making easy the access the visual components. Because I use VB instead of C# you can find here the VB version of the ([original C# sample](https://livecharts.dev/docs/WPF/2.0.0-beta.950/samples.general.mapPoints)).

```
Private _TestSerie1 As ColumnSeries(Of Integer) = New ColumnSeries(Of Integer) With {
    .Values = New Integer() {2, 5, 4, 6, 8, 3, 2, 4, 6},
    .DataLabelsPaint = New SolidColorPaint(New SKColor(30, 30, 30)),
    .DataLabelsPosition = DataLabelsPosition.Top,
    .WhenPointMeasured = Sub(point As Object)                                    
                             If point.Visual IsNot Nothing Then
                                 Dim paint As SolidColorPaint = paints(point.Index Mod paints.Length)
                                 point.Visual.Fill = paint
                             End If
                         End Sub
}
```